# Find and replace all the words starting with a specific character

Tags: c#, ms-word, spire.doc

I have a requirement to replace all words starting with **$** in a Word document

sample:

```
$Address
$Lastname etc.
```

Now at the beginning I must create a list with all words that start with $
After that I replace all words

```
$Lastname -> Waning etc
```

How can I create a list with all words starting with **$** in spiredoc ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression and `FillAllPattern()` method to find the words that start with $ and return results in TextSelection collection.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\$\w+\b");
TextSelection[] selections = document.FindAllPattern(regex);
```

To replace string that matches a specific regex with a new string, use `Document.Replace(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex Pattern, string replace)` method.

Comment: Thank you Alex, this is exactly what i need!

Answer (score 1):

Read the file. Split the words with Split() and keep result in list

```
string s = "word file text";
List<string> words = s.Split(' ');
```

and control items in List

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
foreach(string item in words)
{
    if (item .StartsWith("$")) 
    {
        result.Add(item);
    }
}
```

result returns strings which contain $

Comment: This requires me to get text from Word file, which is not a brilliant way for completing my task. Thanks anyway for your answer.